# Creating a StringBuilder with a large capacity

Tags: vb.net, stringbuilder

I've found the following code in my boss's project:

```
Dim strBuilder As New System.Text.StringBuilder("", 1000000)
```

Before I call him out on it, I'd like to confirm whether this line actually sets a megabyte (or two megabytes in Unicode?) of memory aside for that one stringbuilder?

Comment: i don't think there's ever a reason to do this.

Comment: Agreed.  I just needed some sure footing before confronting my boss.  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That initializes a `Char()` of length 1000000.

So the actual size needed in memory is **2000000 Bytes** = ~2 MB since a char is unicode and needs 2 bytes.

**Edit**: Just in case your boss doesn't believe, this is reflected with ILSpy:

```
// System.Text.StringBuilder
[SecuritySafeCritical]
public unsafe StringBuilder(string value, int startIndex, int length, int capacity)
{
    if (capacity < 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("capacity", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_MustBePositive", new object[]
        {
            "capacity"
        }));
    }
    if (length < 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("length", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_MustBeNonNegNum", new object[]
        {
            "length"
        }));
    }
    if (startIndex < 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("startIndex", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_StartIndex"));
    }
    if (value == null)
    {
        value = string.Empty;
    }
    if (startIndex > value.Length - length)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("length", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_IndexLength"));
    }
    this.m_MaxCapacity = 2147483647;
    if (capacity == 0)
    {
        capacity = 16;
    }
    if (capacity < length)
    {
        capacity = length;
    }
    this.m_ChunkChars = new char[capacity];
    this.m_ChunkLength = length;
    fixed (char* ptr = value)
    {
        StringBuilder.ThreadSafeCopy(ptr + (IntPtr)startIndex, this.m_ChunkChars, 0, length);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try calling  [`GC.GetTotalMemory()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.gettotalmemory.aspx) before and after that allocation, and see if it increases. Note: this is not a good, scientific way to do this, but *may* prove your point.